# Issue on Getting WP Gallery Items In cpt-single.php As Attachments

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, attachments, gallery, images

Having a "Custom Post Type" called `Projects` I am trying to get actual URL of images added into Post Gallery and list them in class other than WordPress built in .gallery.
This is the code which I using in `projects-single.php` but it is not returning any thing(images) and I am not getting any error either!

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'post_parent' => $post->ID
);
$images = get_posts( $args );
foreach($images as $image): ?>
<a rel="lightbox" href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo wp_specialchars( get_the_title($image->ID), 1 ) ?>"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, 'medium' ); ?></a>
<?php endforeach;
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong? is the Post Gallery kind of attachment?

Thanks

Comment: what do you get if you `print_r( $images );` before the `foreach`?

Comment: Hi  karpstrucking  I am getting empty  Array ( )

Comment: Take a look at the database to make sure that query would return anything. Also echo out the ID to make sure it's the correct one. And finally try adding 'post_status' => null to the query.